# Does using the Google Maps client-side Javascript API leak data?

Tags: google

I am currently working on a project where we are using Google Maps to display some data by using the client-side JS API to manually add the points on to the map once the user has clicked on a button.

It has been suggested that using Google Maps may leak our data to Google, and I would like to understand the possibility of this.

Does Google have a way to obtain all the points that are plotted on the map?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Google maps API's [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) agreement, Google has a right to obtain information from  you, when you use Maps JavaScript API. Basically, when using the JavaScript Maps API, the following information is sent to Google:

> - Map size and location for retrieving map tiles and copyrights
> - Addresses for geocoding
> - Direction and Elevation requests
> - Locations around which to search for Places
> - KML when using KmlLayer

Source: [Google Maps FAQs](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos_logging)

Answer (score 3):

By adding javascript files from an external domain, [you also give the owner of that domain control over your web page](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5313290/when-linking-to-an-external-js-file-isnt-this-a-security-risk). However, you can isolate the part the js has access to with [sandboxed iframes](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/), that are [widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=iframe-sandbox).

But even with isolation, if you add the points via their api, google has still access to them. A solution would be to draw the points in a transparent overlay, but that is very hacky.

If you are very concerned about your point data, you [should set up an openstreetmap tile server](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/) and access it with [leaflet](http://switch2osm.org/using-tiles/getting-started-with-leaflet/).